# Change horizontal spacing for subscripts in equation environment

Tags: spacing, equations, subscripts

I would like to adjust the spacing prior and after a subscript to reduce the required horizontal space.

With this small `mwe`

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
    \begin{equation}
        \begin{pmatrix}
            a \\ b \\ c
        \end{pmatrix}_\text{SCR} 
        = x 
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

I get this:

[image]

I would like however to adjust the horizontal spacing before the subscript and make the spacing after the subscript away that it actually overlaps with the euqality sign.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not really sure you want to do it, because it will be confusing your reader.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix}
  a \\ b \\ c
\end{pmatrix}_{\!\!\mathrlap{\mathrm{SCR}}}
= x
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The `\!\!` is for moving the subscript nearer the parenthesis (I always use square brackets for matrices because they give less typographic problems).

You can give the subscript some width, which will be less confusing, with `\mathmakebox` instead of `\mathrlap` (note that `\mathrlap{...}` is equivalent to `\mathmakebox[0pt][l]{...}`).

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix}
  a \\ b \\ c
\end{pmatrix}_{\!\!\mathmakebox[1em][l]{\mathrm{SCR}}}
= x
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Adjust the length (here 1em) to your needs.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your prompt answer. I think I will midigate the problem a bit with some `~`. The problem is I don't really want to split the equation over two lines.

Comment: @magu_ Instead of adding spaces, use `\mathmakebox[1em][l]{\mathrm{SRC}}` that will make the subscript 1em wide to TeX's eyes; `\mathrlap` is equivalent to `\mathmakebox[0pt][l]`

Comment: Thx again. This is defently less hacky.